# Replication between three servers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 2 way replication (merge) between 2 servers, Let's say between server A and server B
Can i add another server and make another 2 way replication (between server A and the new server c) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The canonical use case for merge replication is a set of disconnected clients that need to synchronize with a master database at corporate headquarters. In your example, A is the headquarters and B & C are the disconnected clients.